# Change displayed business flow process on form

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

Supppose I have two different business process flow for an entity, is it possible, from the `onLoad` event of the form, to change which flow is displayed ?

Should I try and modify the order in which the flows are shown depending on some conditions ? If that is even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You want `Xrm.Page.data.process.setActiveProcess(processId, callbackFunction)`

See [Xrm.Page.data.process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817878(v=crm.7).aspx) for reference

Comment: Thanks, I just found the MSDN page for this :P